Help understanding the following step
I came across something I don't understand in Sakurai & Napolitano book, page 446:

$$\begin{align}
\langle\Psi|U_{\text{ext}}|\Psi\rangle &= \sum_i \int\mathrm{d}^3 x_i^{\prime}\langle\Psi|V_{\text{ext}}(\mathbf{x}_i)|\mathbf{x}_i^{\prime}\rangle\langle\mathbf{x}_i^{\prime}|\Psi\rangle = \sum_i \int\mathrm{d}^3 x_i^{\prime}V_{\text{ext}}(\mathbf{x}_i^{\prime})\langle\Psi|\mathbf{x}_i^{\prime}\rangle\langle\mathbf{x}_i^{\prime}|\Psi\rangle \\
&=\sum_i \int\mathrm{d}^3 x_1^{\prime}\mathrm{d}^3 x_2^{\prime}\cdots\mathrm{d}^3 x_i^{\prime} \cdots \mathrm{d}^3 x_N^{\prime}V_{\text{ext}}(\mathbf{x}_i^{\prime}) \\ 
&\quad \, \times \Psi^{\ast}(\mathbf{x}_1^{\prime}, \mathbf{x}_2^{\prime}, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_i^{\prime}, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_N^{\prime})\Psi (\mathbf{x}_1^{\prime}, \mathbf{x}_2^{\prime}, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_i^{\prime}, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_N^{\prime}). 
\end{align} \tag{7.82}$$

My question is: how did they obtain the last step in the derivation?
For clarity, the physical system discussed is $N$ identical particles and $x_i$ is the position of the $i$-th particle, with $U_{\text{ext}}=\displaystyle \sum\limits_i V_{\text{ext}}(x_i)$.
I want to add something.
I don't think that one can say $\langle x_i|\Psi\rangle =\Psi(x_1,x_2...,x_i.,x_n)$ but what holds is:
$$\langle x_n|\otimes\langle x_{n-1}|\ldots \otimes \langle x_1||\Psi\rangle =\Psi(x_1,x_2...,x_i.,x_n).$$
That is because the system discussed is $N$ particles.

Please don't use images or screenshots for equations and text. Instead, use MathJax.

What exactly is unclear in the derivation?

How did the author evaluated the term $<\Psi|x_i><x_i|\Psi>$? To my understanding:  $<x_i|\Psi>=\int{d^3y_1...d^3y_n\Psi(y_1,....,y_n)\delta(Y-x_i)}$ where Y is the vector in this N dimensional space

@TobiasFünke I submitted an edit that aimed to replace the image with MathJax syntax, with other adjustments to the body (grammar and syntax), but it was rejected.
